# How do I find the size of a DB2 (luw) database?

Tags: database, db2, admin, db2-luw

I know you can look at the size of an uncompressed backup, but that's not practical.

Is there a command to find the size of the database while it is online? (In Linux/Unix/windows)

Comment: I imagine what you meant to ask was how to do this for a DB2 LUW database. The answer(s) for other DB2 platforms (IBM i & z/OS) would be different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When connected to a database as db2admin (or with similar permissions), use the following command:

```
 call get_dbsize_info(?,?,?,-1);
```

The first three parameters are output parameters:

```
Value of output parameters
--------------------------
Parameter Name  : SNAPSHOTTIMESTAMP
Parameter Value : 2014-06-17-13.59.55.049000

Parameter Name  : DATABASESIZE
Parameter Value : 334801764352

Parameter Name  : DATABASECAPACITY
Parameter Value : 1115940028416

Return Status = 0
```

The size is given in bytes, so divide by 1024^3 to get Gb.

The final parameter is how often the snapshot is refreshed. -1 is to use default settings.

[Further reading...](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_8.2.0/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/admin/r0011863.htm?lang=en)

Note: This command does not take into account logs, etc. - so, it may appear much larger on disk.

Answer (score 1):

Use `db2top`

<kbd>l</kbd>(for session)

<kbd>p</kbd>(when press small p it will show the total size of db n used size of db)

Comment: How exactly have you created the I and P keys in your post? Pretty cool! Is db2top only for UNIX?

Comment: @ESP you use the HTML tag `<kbd></kbd>`

Answer (score 1):

For specific schema, in KBytes, use:

```
SELECT sum(TOTAL_P_SIZE) FROM (
SELECT TABNAME, (DATA_OBJECT_P_SIZE + INDEX_OBJECT_P_SIZE + LONG_OBJECT_P_SIZE +
LOB_OBJECT_P_SIZE + XML_OBJECT_P_SIZE) as TOTAL_P_SIZE
FROM SYSIBMADM.ADMINTABINFO
WHERE TABSCHEMA='PUBLIC'
)
```

Reference: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-do-i-find-out-disk-space-usage-managing-server-octigate-database-tables

Comment: only thing thing that worked for me using a db2 database and needing to use pure sql with some django tables which I think might have messed up the other commands

Answer (score 0):

Following command will show you memory used by database online :

```
db2pd -dbptnmem
```

You can monitor variety of stuff with db2pd command :

```
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=commands-db2pd-monitor-troubleshoot-db2-engine-activities
```